# get property from UserAgent object (koa-useragent)

Tags: javascript, koa

```
UserAgent {
  _agent: {
    isYaBrowser: false,
    isAuthoritative: true,
    isMobile: true,
    isMobileNative: false,
    isTablet: false,
    isiPad: false,
    isiPod: false,
    isiPhone: false,
    isiPhoneNative: false,
    isAndroid: true,
    isAndroidNative: false,
    isBlackberry: false,
    isOpera: false,
    isIE: false,
    isEdge: false,
    isIECompatibilityMode: false,
    isSafari: false,
    isFirefox: false,
    isWebkit: false,
    isChrome: true,
    isKonqueror: false,
    isOmniWeb: false,
    isSeaMonkey: false,
    isFlock: false,
    isAmaya: false,
    isPhantomJS: false,
    isEpiphany: false,
    isDesktop: false,
    isWindows: false,
    isLinux: true,
    isLinux64: false,
    isMac: false,
    isChromeOS: false,
    isBada: false,
    isSamsung: false,
    isRaspberry: false,
    isBot: false,
    isCurl: false,
    isAndroidTablet: false,
    isWinJs: false,
    isKindleFire: false,
    isSilk: false,
    isCaptive: false,
    isSmartTV: false,
    isUC: false,
    isFacebook: false,
    isAlamoFire: false,
    isElectron: false,
    silkAccelerated: false,
    browser: 'Chrome',
    os: 'Linux',
    platform: 'Android',
    geoIp: {},
    isWechat: false,
    electronVersion: ''
  }
}
```

I use this package for getting user agent https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-useragent . Here how I get object you see above `util.inspect(ctx.userAgent)` , but it is string. I've tried to make `JSON.parse(util.inspect(ctx.userAgent))` , but it doesn't work this way. How can I parse this string or convert it to object , to get properties inside of `_agent` ?

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.userAgent._agent.isMobile` - you don't need call inspect object